# Google Maps modify/remove populated polylines

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am working with Google maps API(latest). So far, i can able to create and removing(on add operation) route with the help of polylines and markers.

Problem is when i try to modify(on update mode) the maps populates(dynamically) the route which i saved but if try to remove/modify existing route the marker removes but polyline dont.

tried `poly.setMap(null);`. but doesn't work.

on **page load** :

[image]

after removing any **marker** : (the last one got removed)

[image]

And you can see **marker** has been removed but **polyline** is still there

**CODE**(not working on fiddle):

```js
var poly;
var map;
var markers = new Array();

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 24.926294,
      lng: 67.022095
    } // Center the map on Pakistan.
  });

  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  });
  poly.setMap(map);

  // if update/edit model populate map dynamically
  populateLatLng();

  // Add a listener for the click event
  map.addListener('click', addLatLng);

  map.addListener('click', function() {
    getPathVariableCode(poly);
  });
}

function populateLatLng() {
  var path = '[{"lat":24.96078338154793,"lng":67.10892827306634},{"lat":24.934323836524374,"lng":67.07047612462884},{"lat":24.926851877301345,"lng":67.08111912999993},{"lat":24.90816999805268,"lng":67.06669957433587},{"lat":24.917822655664953,"lng":67.0519366959179},{"lat":24.911102310371437,"lng":67.03740863310293}]' //dynamic array
  path = JSON.parse(path);

  for (k = 0; k < path.length; k++) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: path[k],
      title: '#' + k,
      map: map
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: path,
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
      removePoint(marker);
    });
  }
}

// Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
function addLatLng(event) {
  console.log("event", event);
  var path = poly.getPath();

  // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
  // and it will automatically appear.
  path.push(event.latLng);

  // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
    map: map
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  console.log(markers.length - 1, event.latLng);
  poly.getPath().setAt(markers.length - 1, event.latLng);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
    removePoint(marker);
  });
}

function getPathVariableCode(line) {
  var getLocation = '';
  var locationArr = [];
  var pathArr = line.getPath();
  for (var i = 0; i < pathArr.length; i++) {
    var codeStr = [];
    codeStr = {
      'lat': pathArr.getAt(i).lat(),
      'lng': pathArr.getAt(i).lng()
    };
    locationArr.push(codeStr);
    document.getElementById('locationCordinates').value = JSON.stringify(locationArr);
  }
};

function removePoint(marker) {

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i] === marker) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
      markers.splice(i, 1);
      poly.getPath().removeAt(i);
      getPathVariableCode(poly);

    }
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: `polyline` need to be outside of `for` loop. i think

Comment: @User863 Yeah, it removes polyline. but remaining markers are not able to remove.

Comment: Why are you creating the Polyline twice? Once in initMap and once in populateLatLng function? Why are you creating the polyline **within** the for loop, which essentially recreates the Polyline at each iteration? etc.

Comment: @MrUpsidown i am working on update process. so i populate the markers & polylines from dynamic array. if ill not use in populatelatlang() function then the markers will show on map but polyline will not.

Comment: No. Read your code again. Anyway, as already mentioned, you need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates **one** issue, and clearly explains what your code is doing, what doesn't work, what you have tried, etc. That is: a clear problem description. I am now removing my answer since you don't seem to need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite problematic but I was able to successfully get a simplified working version of what you're trying to achieve here (if I understood correctly).

Try the code below. Just click on the map to add markers and then click on those markers to remove both the markers and their corresponding lines.

```
var poly;
var map;
var markers = new Array();

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {
            lat: 24.926294,
            lng: 67.022095
        } // Center the map on Pakistan.
    });

    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly.setMap(map);

    // Add a listener for the click event
    map.addListener('click', addLatLng);
}

// Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
function addLatLng(event, path = false) {
    console.log("event", event);
    var path = poly.getPath();

    // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
    // and it will automatically appear.
    path.push(event.latLng);

    // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        title: '#' + path.getLength(),
        map: map,
        id: new Date()
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    console.log(markers.length - 1, event.latLng);
    poly.getPath().setAt(markers.length - 1, event.latLng);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
        removePoint(marker);
    });
}

function removePoint(marker) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].id === marker.id) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
            markers.splice(i, 1);
            poly.getPath().removeAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps point you in the right direction.